# Model is not part of any target. Add the model to a target to enable generation of the model class

Tags: ios

I'm trying to add the GoogleNetPlaces Model to my app but I'm getting an error saying "Model is not part of any target. Add the model to a target to enable generation of the model class."

[image]

When I dragged it into the resources folder of the app, I did make sure to add the app as a target..

Comment: Things sound a it vague. (1) Are you talking about CoreML? It doesn't appear so. (2) If not, what *exactly* are you trying to do? Thanks for the *image* of the error - but what about the *details*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add `.mlmodel` file to *Compile Source*

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

You say you dragged it into the `Resources` folder of the project which sounds like it might be a Folder Reference (blue) in your Xcode project, rather than a Group (yellow).  Xcode will only automatically generate classes for models that are explicitly added to the Target, while ignoring models that are in Folders.

I put my models into a `Models` folder and made sure to add the folder to Xcode as a Group (with a yellow icon) and it works fine.

[image: Adding Groups and Folders to Xcode]